# subgradient of composition

Tags: calculus, optimization

Are there general rules or references of subgradient of composition? For example, consider the composition $f(x)=h(g(x))$ where $h$ is convex nondecreasing and $g$ is convex, then the subgradient of $f$ can be computed as in [slide 15](https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee364b/lectures/subgradients_slides.pdf). However, what if $h$ is concave nondecreasing?

Comment: Subgradient is only defined for convex function.